# Unhook key shortcuts on websites

Tags: web-browser, keyboard-shortcuts

There are websites that react on certain key combinations. For example certain websites intercept `Ctrl + 1` ... `Ctrl + 9` key combinations. I have those shortcuts set up in browser for tab navigation: `Ctrl + 1` goes to the first tab, `Ctrl + 2` goes to the second, etc. Because the websites intercept those keys the browser no longer reacts to them.

I'm looking for a way to "unhook" those key. Maybe there's an extension that can help me?

Comment: Welcome indigoer! Which operating system(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://superuser.com/a/595885/1167865) answers the question.

### Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         1...9 shortcuts
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  stops keydown event propagation for keys from 1 to 9 inclusive
// @author       You
// @grant        none
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==


var keycodes = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58] // Keycode for '1,..9', add more keycodes to disable other key captures

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // alert(e.keyCode); //uncomment to find out the keycode for any given key
    if (keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1)
    {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    return false;
});
```